# Compact a Database in OLEDB

Tags: oledb

Does anyone know how to compact a SQL Server CE 4.0 database using OLEDB?

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.

SQL Server CE does not support the DBCC SHRINKDATABASE command.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you are looking for either Compact or autoshrink
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174034.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172411.aspx

Comment: I am using C++ not C#/.NET :(.